# А если «нет»(,) — тоже обидится

Tags: пунктуация, запятая-перед-тире

Нужна запятая?

> Я думаю, что, если я отвечу «да», она обидится, а если «нет»(,) — тоже обидится.

Comment: Леопольд! *Обид**и**тся*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Думаю, что, если я отвечу «да», она обидится, а если «нет» — тоже обидится.*

Я бы не стала ставить запятую (а первое "я", считаю, лучше не использовать).

По идее, тире здесь и ставится **вместо** запятой — для обозначения большей паузы при пропуске подлежащего. Вот предполагаемое полное предложение:
Думаю, что, если я отвечу «да», она обидится, а если [отвечу, скажу] «нет», [она] тоже обидится.

*Такая вот жизнь сейчас (кивни головой, если согласен, а если нет — тоже кивни)* (Андрей Удалов. Правил нет. Девушки, успех и баян).
*По словам Пескова, если президент получит премию, это будет прекрасно, а если нет — тоже замечательно* (из статьи).

Answer (score 2):

Правильно:

*Я думаю, что, если я отвечу «да», она обидится, **а если «нет» — тоже обидится.***

Пояснение

Восстанавливаем предложение: Я *думаю, что, если я отвечу «да», она обидится, а если **я отвечу «нет», то тоже обидится.***

Здесь перед ***ТО*** стоит запятая, а в неполном предложении запятая **замещается** тире.

Сочетание знаков (**дополнительное** тире) выглядит как **единый знак** и будет неуместным.